# average and standard deviation of distribution given by sum with exponential form

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, exponential-function, approximation

We have a distribution with D sample given by:

$F(k)=\sum_{j=1}^N  w_j(k)\times p_j(k)$

so k=1...D generating samples F(1)...F(D)

and

$\sum_{j=1}^N  w_j(k) = 1$

also, $\ w$ has the form

$w \equiv A^B$

so

$F(k)=\sum_{j=1}^N \ [A_j(k)]^B\times p_j(k)$

Question:
What is the average and standard deviation of distribution F given as a function of B.

Approximations are welcome and if the ratio $\ Average(F) \over Standard Deviation(F)$ offers a simplifications would be great.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I am a physicist...in this I look to mathematicians for help...

Comment: I am happy to work this myself but could definitely use some direction eg book or website with some examples or methods.